# How to block HTTP request in Apache CXF JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I have undergone a situation where I need to accept only `https` requests and need to block `http` request. I don't know how to achieve this in `CXF` . I am using SOAP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a transport policy, it will restrict requests to HTTPS.  For example:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="..." xmlns:sp="...">
  <sp:TransportBinding>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:TransportToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportToken>
        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Layout>
        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:TransportBinding>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .Need to access specific webmethod via only Https not via Http